# Judging a bicycle show

Tags: vintage, customization

At the end of the month, I'm helping out at a Car Show that has a new Bicycle division.  They want me to judge because I work in the bike industry.  I've never done this, and any recommendations would be helpful.  We are doing two categories, Custom & Vintage, and I need help with what criteria to judge and how to weight it(points per category), and any other advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd guess for vintage, the judging would be similar to a classic car.

Comment: I'm thinking so too.  And I'm pretty well-versed on old Schwinns and stuff, I'm just hoping people don't bring a bunch of wood-wheels or something I'm not too familiar with...  It would be awesome to see, but it would be a bitch to come up with a quantifiable criteria for saying one is better than the other

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things i would consider, some could possibly be grouped together. Perhaps others can add on with more answers.

**Custom Class**

- Originality/Creativity
- Function 
  *Can you actually ride it semi comfortably or is it just cool looking
  *Can it do something normal bikes can't?
- Use of colors or materials (could lump into creativity)
- Wow factor
- Overall theme

**Vintage Class**

- Period correctness (50's era components on a 50's era cycle)
- Original parts (as much as possible)
- Cleanliness
- Paint/Chrome quality (new or original)
- Function (are all required parts present and in working order)

For your points system, decide on what things you would like to judge , using my list as an example you could give each a 20 point value, 5 topics totaling 100 points maximum - Highest score wins

Comment: Normally for classic cars, theres something like how well it runs. Not sure you can do that for a bike, but still.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that as well, but wasn't sure how to apply it to the bicycle platform, i added function to the vintage class portion as well.

Answer (score 6):

**METHOD** Write up your marking criteria before seeing any entries.  That will help you not be swayed by bikes you like personally.

**SCORE** Allocate 100 points per entrant, with say 10 for finish, 10 for rideability/functionality, 10 for originality etc.  Leave yourself 10 points for wow-factor, and 10 points for whatever you didn't expect.

That will help you be more objective, repeatable, and be able to defend your scores.

**SHARE** If there's a bunch of bikes, consider doing it as a tag team with someone else.  Discussing the display will help show things you might not notice straight away by yourself.

**TIME** Use a timer - allocate the same amount of time to judging each bike... no less than 2 minutes and no more than 3 for example, will take you between 3 hours 20 min and 5 hours to judge 100 bikes.  You want judging done by early afternoon so people can see the ribbons/awards.  So start judging from 0900.

**AWARDS** Have shiny ribbons and certificates for the winners to take home and keep.  If there are cups they tend to be returned after 10 months for the next year's winner.